# Refresh value every second Tkinter

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter

So Here i have a function:

```
def test():
    global value

    if value ==0:
        value=1
        return True

    else:
        value=0
        return False
```

Here is what I come up with:

```
import tkinter as tk

value=0




while True:
    root = tk.Tk()
    root.title("my title")
    root.geometry('200x150')
    root.configure(background='black')

    clock_frame = tk.Label(root, font = ('caviar dreams', 130), bg='black')
    clock_frame.pack()

    def test():
        global value

        if value ==0:
            value=1
            return True

        else:
            value=0
            return False



    if test() is True:
        clock_frame.config(text="HelloWorld",fg="red")


    else:

        clock_frame.config(text="HelloWorld",fg="white")



    root.mainloop()
```

I want to display the result of this in a Tkinter GUI. I want to change a label while the function is True or False. I want this change to happen every second.
But i don't know how to do it.

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `after()` to periodically call `test()` and update the label:

```
import tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()
root.geometry('+100+100')
root.config(bg='black')

clock = tk.Label(root, text='HelloWorld', font=('caviar dreams', 130), bg='black')
clock.pack()

value = 0

def test():
    global value
    value = 1 - value
    return value == 1

def update():
    color = 'red' if test() else 'white'
    clock.config(fg=color)
    root.after(1000, update) # call update() after 1 second

update() # start the periodic update
root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the after method then. The syntax is like this: widget.after(milisecond, action). First you add the time to wait and next you add the action to do.

Comment: This doesn't provide an answer to this problem.sleep will make tkinter application freezed.

Comment: If yes, please mark my answer as correct and upvote it

Comment: Could you explain it to me on my example ? It will be awesome

Comment: First create a function that does what you want. Then add .after to the last widget that will be made before the function is executed. So if the last widget that will be made is a label called txt, then do 

txt.after(delaytime, function)

Answer (score -2):

help this is result recurs like this

Total Account: 13
Total Account: 13

```
def update():
        file = open("list.txt", "r")
        line_count = 0
        for line in file:
            if line != "\n":
              line_count += 1
        file.close()
        Label(kariata,bg="white", text=('Total Account:',(line_count)) , fg="green", font="bold").pack()

        kariata.after(1000, update) # call update() after 1 second
        
        
  update() # start the periodic update
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).